# Error Trying to Use Multiple SCSS files in Jekyll

Tags: css, sass, jekyll

I am working on a website with Jekyll. I want to use multiple SCSS files. I was able to successfully add a main file but I am having issues after that.

My directory structure is:

```
_sass/main.scss

_sass/post.scss

_sass/apps/app1.scss

_sass/apps/app2.scss
```

There is a corresponding scss file for each of these in `assets/css`. For example, `assets/css/main.scss`.

Each file in the `_sass` directory contains my styles. Each file in the `assets/css` contains code such as

```
---
---
@import "main";
```

I am able to access my `assets/css/main.css` file when I bundle the website.

However, I get the following error and cannot access the other files.

```
Conversion error: Jekyll::Converters::Scss encountered an error while converting 'assets/css/post.scss':
                    expected "{".
             Error: expected "{".
             Error: Run jekyll build --trace for more information.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching, I found the answer. It appears that a file in the `_sass` folder and the `assets/css/` folder cannot have the same name. Changing the name of one of them fixed the issue.